# Avoid for loop with MongoDB update

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm using PyMongo to process and update some data.

In my DB, I have a collection of foods and a collection of recipes. Every recipe has one food Document linked to it, and there are some "repeated" recipes (recipes which have the same food Document). One of the recipes of every "repeated" group is marked as the original.

I want to add a new field in the food that stores the id of the original recipe in which it appeared. For that, I am looping through every food document, getting the recipe which has that food and is marked as the original, and storing this recipe's id in the actual food document:

```
for food in stored_food:
    recipe = db.recipes.find_one({"food":food_id, "original":True})
    db.food.update_one({"_id": food_id}, {"original_recipe": recipe['_id]})
```

This piece of code works for me, but there are too many items in the DB, so I need to think of an alternative solution. I was wondering if I can make one "bulk" update of some sort so that I don't have to iterate every food in the DB.

The code I provided is not exactly what I wrote, so there may be syntax errors. Also, I can't change the data structure. Hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check `update_many()`

Comment: Yes. I have investigated those methods but the problem in general is that I need to update every food item with the result of another query (the original recipe of each food). For that query I need to know the id of every food I am updating, so I don't know how to do it without a for loop.

Comment: You can use the Bulk Write method. This will allow send one bulk operation to the server and get back one result.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to do it. It is a matter of building an aggregation pipeline:

```
    [{
        '$lookup': {'from' : 'recipe',
                'localField' : '_id',
                'foreignField' : 'food',
                'as' : 'recipe'
        },
    },
    {
        '$match':{'food.original':true, 'original_recipe': {"$exists": False}},
    },
    {
        '$unwind': "$recipe"
    },
    {
        '$addFields': {
            "original_recipe": "$recipe._id"
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'recipe': 0
        }
    },
    {
        '$merge':{'into': 'food', 'on': '_id'}
    }]
```

First stage is add the whole recipe that matches to every food document in the collection. I unwind it so it is not a list of recipes for each food, but one recipe per food. I then add the desired field and delete the whole recipe from each document. Finally, I merge the collections so it stays the same.